# Call asp.net web service from PHP with multiple parameters

Tags: php, web-services, asmx

I'm using a method using SoapClient class in a php page to call a web service in an asp.net site.

Here is the php code.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://testurl/Test.asmx?WSDL");

$params = array( 'Param1'  => 'Hello', 
                'Param2' => 'World!');

$result = $client->TestMethod($params)->TestMethodResult;

echo $result;
```

The problem is, I'm only getting the first parameter (Param1) "Hello" back and seems like there is an issue with Param2. 
Here is the asp.net method.

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(string Param1, string Param2) 
{
    return Param1 + " " +  Param2; 
}
```

What am I missing to get `Hello World!` in the response?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://testurl/Test.asmx?WSDL");
$params->Param1 = 'Hello';
$params->Param2 = 'World!';    
$result = $client->TestMethod($params)->TestMethodResult;
```

Comment: One quick question. The reason my code did't work is b/c it was being passed as one single param of type array?

Comment: can you tell me where come TestMethodResult ?

Comment: what is the $params object? how do i set it?

Answer (score 1):

I was googling for multi-parameter calling.
All the thread did not tell the following.
When php call .asmx  web service, the passing of parameters MUST MATCH the variables used in the web service of :

```
public string XYZ(string p, string q)
```

The web service call has to be something like :

```
$params = array( "p"  => $name1,    "q" => $name2 );
```

p, q pairs must be named and clarified in php calling.

Answer (score 0):

```
***********index.php******************
<?php
require_once("lib/nusoap.php"); 
 $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:1966/ListAndishmandan/WebServiseFinal.asmx?WSDL");

    $params = array( 'Param1'  => 'Moslem', 
                    'Param2' => 'Ganji!');

    $result = $client->TestMethod($params)->TestMethodResult;

    print_r( $result);
    $params = array( 'Param1'  => 'Moslem', 
                    'Param2' => 'Ganji!');
echo "\n \r";
    $result2 = $client->ShowNameFamely($params)->ShowNameFamelyResult;

    print_r( $result2);
?>

    *******************WebServiseFinal.asmx?WSDL**************************
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebServiseFinal
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebServiseFinal : System.Web.Services.WebService {

        public WebServiseFinal () {

            //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
           //InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string TestMethod(string Param1, string Param2)
        {
            return Param1 + " " + Param2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string ShowNameFamely(string Param1, string Param2)
        {
            return Param1 + " " + Param2;
        }

    }
```

Comment: $result2 = $client->ShowNameFamely($params)->ShowNameFamelyResult;