# Call asp.net web service from PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap, web

I've made ASP.NET web service, which contains one initial method called HelloWorld. I want to access to mentioned method using php and following code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:4925/Service1.asmx?WSDL");

$result = $client->HelloWorld()->TestMethodResult;
echo $result;
```

When I run php script, i get following error:

```
***Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$TestMethodResult in C:\wamp\www\probe\servis.php on line 8***
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is `TestMethodResult` correct?

Comment: Yes, send the code for TestMethodResult

Comment: I used following post as star guide, but stopped with given problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711502/call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: what does __getFunctions return?

Comment: Do you really need to use SOAP? Could you use JSON or REST instead? SOAP is horribly bloated and slow; if you can use something quicker, I'd strongly recommend it. (and if you're writing both ends of the service, there's no reason why not)

Comment: How to do this with json or rest ?

Comment: Is there any tutorial how to do this with JSON and REST ?PLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since HelloWorld is the method you are trying to call, try:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('HelloWord', $params);
```

or

```
$result = $client->HelloWorld($params);
```

Where `$params` are any parameters you need to send for the method.

Comment: Can you provide results of `$client->__getFunctions()`?

Comment: This works: $params = array('bla'=>'opala');
$response  = $client->HelloWorld($params);
var_dump($response);
echo "$response->HelloWorldResult";

Comment: @Mr.M Ahh... so HelloWorld is the actual method not TestMethodResult.  I guess I don't know where. I have updated the answer.