# Consuming a VB.NET web service from PHP

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I'm relatively new to PHP, and totally new to VB.NET / Web Services / SOAP / XML, and i'm having trouble to make my PHP communicate with the VB.NET web service.

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://10.0.0.2/wsteste/Service1.asmx?wsdl");
    $param = array("usuario" => "name", "senha" => "test");
    $response = $client->__soapCall("HelloWorld", $param);  
    print_r($response);
?>
```

And here is the VB.NET asmx.

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal usuario As String, ByVal senha As String) As String
        Return usuario & " - " & senha
    End Function

End Class
```

And here is what printed on the browser:

`stdClass Object ( [HelloWorldResult] => - )`

It was supposed to return `name - test`, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the PHP SOAP Client is passing the parameters without the names. So usuario nor senha means nothing to the HelloWorld method.

I would try something like

```
$client->HelloWorld(array("usuario"=>"name", "senha"=>"test"));
```

Haven tested though.

EDIT

From this question [Call asp.net web service from PHP with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711502/call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters)

Pass your params like this

```
$params->usuario = 'name';
$params->senha = 'test';
$client->HelloWorld($params);
```

Comment: Nop, still returning `stdClass Object ( [HelloWorldResult] => - )` thank you, anyway =)

Comment: Can you use firebug or similar to see whats the PHP soap message format is? I think that would give you a clue

Comment: it wont show me anything besides the returned message, with firebug and firephp

Comment: The things is that the method is returning a concat string. But the 2 input vars are empty. So either the client is not sending them or is sending them incorrectly. I'm not very experienced in .net webservices, and I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: What do you mean the vars are empty? Am i not setting a value to `usuario` var with `"usuario" => "name"`?

Comment: Still returning me the same

Comment: Changed the VB.net web service to C#, and it started to work. Thank you for your help