# Using PFC shipping API in PHP

Tags: php, api

I am trying to use pfc shippiong api
http://www.pfcexpress.com/webservice/EnAPIDoc.html

I am trying to run the simple getCountry method, the first one on that page.
You can also find it working on this page
http://bit.ly/1Lq4t6G
Just use the key pfc123456789 and hit search

My problem is that their example on the tutorial in the first link is for .Net and I know php only and integrating this in php

According to their tutorial

FOR .NET
    First step:In your own project:asp.net,add web quotation,Provide the API service website address offered by PFC. Be assumed to be:"http://pfcexpress.com/webservice/APIWebService.asmx"

```
Second step:Initialization,then use the method,can obtain the data
pfc.pfcwebservice p=new pfc.pfcwebservice();
string result = p.getCountry(secretkey);
```

I am using curl for php
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.pfcexpress.com/webservice/APIWebService.asmx/getCountry',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                secretkey => '2add5e13-3b85-45a9-9fcc-4b739de2b1b784342'
            )
        ));

```
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $r = mb_convert_encoding($resp,'ISO-8859-1','utf-8');
    print_r($r);

    curl_close($curl);
```

But no success.
But getting the following error

```
[InvalidOperationException: 因 URL 意外地以“/getCountry”结束，请求格式无法识别。]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +489333
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +212
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +346
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I don't understand .Net error

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As far as i can find out then you need to use 'SOAP' to access .net 'asmx' services. I did try to make a working example. However, 'SOAP' i have not used. Internet search: 'use asmx service from php' is a start. SO Question: [call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711502/call-asp-net-web-service-from-php-with-multiple-parameters)

Comment: Thanks Ryan
Using soap was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving from CURL to SOAP, as pointed by Ryan above in the comments.
**We need to use SOAP to connect to .net 'asmx' services**